# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Cpage#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and have been trying to create a simple form, but I keep receiving  this error

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Cpage#new
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cpage"} missing
>   required keys: [:id]

Here is the line its referring to:

```
<%= form_for :cpage, url: cpage_path do |f| %>
```

Here are my routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
signin_claim GET    /signin/claim(.:format)   signin#claim

cpage_index GET    /cpage(.:format)          cpage#index
POST   /cpage(.:format)          cpage#create

new_cpage GET    /cpage/new(.:format)      cpage#new

edit_cpage GET    /cpage/:id/edit(.:format) cpage#edit
cpage GET    /cpage/:id(.:format)      cpage#show

PATCH  /cpage/:id(.:format)      cpage#update

PUT    /cpage/:id(.:format)      cpage#update

DELETE /cpage/:id(.:format)      cpage#destroy

root GET    /                         signin#claim
```

Formatting on here is weird. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you define the form, you're passing in a method `cpage_path` that gives an error. You can reproduce that error if you go into the Rails console:

```
rails c
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.cpage_path
=> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches ...
```

And if you look at the error you should see a section that says `missing required keys: [:id]`. This is the important part; you tried to call a route helper that requires an id argument, so a valid way to call that helper would be `cpage_path(123)` and so forth.

If you want the URL for creating a new resource, it's likely something like `new_cpage_path()` instead (no arguments needed for that one). You can confirm by going to your console and tying `rake routes`; the route helper prefix is listed in the left-most column, so you should see an entry for `new_cpage`, an entry for `cpage`, `cpages`, etc.